# How to change the request of each input in Python's range() function

Tags: python, range

I'm trying to create a program in which a user input the number of bottles he or she returned on a day of the week. It should go like this:

```
Please enter the number of bottles for each day:
Sunday:
```

These should appear simultaneously. As the user inputs an integer for each day, the subsequent should appear. However, I can't achieve that. How is this done?
Here is my code, for reference:

```
inputBottles = 0
totalBottles = 0
refund = totalBottles * 0.10
x = 0

for x in range(7):
    inputBottles = int(input("Please enter the number of bottles for each day: "))

    totalBottles = totalBottles + inputBottles

print("")
print("You entered a total of", totalBottles, "bottles.")
print("Your pay-out total is", int(refund), "at a rate of $0.10 per bottle.")
print("")
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? If the problem is, that your refund is 0, well you will have to calculate it

Comment: @user8408080 Yes, that too is an issue, but I haven't gotten there yet (I'm brand new to Python). The outcome should look as I described: the user should have the option to input 7 days worth of bottle amounts, but instead of each input saying "Please enter the number of bottles for return," I'd like them to each be a day of the week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so first of all I listed all the weekdays in the list `weekdays`. Then I defined a function `refund` which can calculate your refund given the total amount of bottles and the refund rate. Afterwards I only need to loop over the weekdays and ask for the amount of bottles each day. Then I can calculate the refund and print it in the format `:.2f` which means "Every digit before the point and two digits after the point"

```
inputBottles = 0
totalBottles = 0

weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
            "Sunday"]

def refund(totalBottles, rate):
    return totalBottles * rate

print("Please enter the number of bottles for each day: ")
for day in weekdays:
    inputBottles = int(input("{}: \t".format(day)))

    totalBottles = totalBottles + inputBottles

print("")
print("You entered a total of", totalBottles, "bottles.")
print("Your pay-out total is {:.2f} at a rate of $0.10 per bottle.".format(refund(totalBottles, 0.10)))
print("")
```

Side note: This is not really what stackoverflow is for; this is more for specific programming problems not general implementation